# Can't Assign Component to Variable When Checking for Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

This code works:

```
import React from 'react'
import { MyComponent } from './components'


export const NewComponent = props => {
  const {
    isValid,
  } = props

  const UseComponent = MyComponent

  return (
    <>
        <UseComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```

But this code does **not** work:

```
import React from 'react'
import { MyComponent } from './components'


export const NewComponent = props => {
  const {
    isSet,
  } = props

  const UseComponent = isSet && MyComponent

  return (
    <>
        <UseComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```

I.e., I am trying to see whether or not the prop `isSet` is being used or not.  If it is being used, then I want to render the component.  If not, then not.

But when I try to do this vis-a-vis assigning it to a variable, I get the following error message:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Is there a way to assign my component to a variable so that it renders if the prop is used, but does not render if it is not used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isSet && MyComponent` asserts to a `boolean` (forced conversion). Use a `ternary operator`

```
const UseComponent = isSet ? MyComponent : React.Fragment
```

Or good old `if`

```
let UseComponent = React.Fragment

if(isSet) UseComponent = MyComponent
```

But usually in a use case like yours we just use `conditional rendering`

```
return isSet ? <MyComponent /> : null
```

Comment: That did it - thanks :).  In this case I don't want to use conditional rendering, since I have a number of components that I'm conditionally rendering -- and it was getting a bit messy in my return statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this,

```
export const NewComponent = props => {
  const {
    isSet,
  } = props

  const UseComponent = MyComponent

  return (
    <>
        {isSet && <UseComponent />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: No need of assigning component to a new variable in this case

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but might be OP want to rename the component for some other purpose.